# SQL where clause parameterization

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

I am trying to parameterize certain where clauses to standardized my Postgres SQL scripts for DB monitoring. But have not found a solution that will allow me to have the following script run successfully

```
variablename = "2021-04-08 00:00:00"

select * from table1
where log_date > variablename;

select * from table2
where log_date > variablename;
```

Ideally, I would be able to run each script separately, but being able to find/replace the variable line would go a long way for productivity.

Edit: I am currently using DBeaver to run my scripts

Comment: Which tool do you use to run the scripts?

Comment: I am using DBeaver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in DBeaver I figured out you can use Dynamic Parameter Bindings feature.
https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/SQL-Execution#dynamic-parameter-bindings

Here is a quick visual demo of how to use it:
https://twitter.com/dbeaver_news/status/1085222860841512960?lang=en

```
select * from table1
where log_date > :variablename;
```

When executing the query DBeaver will prompt you for the value desired and remember it when running another query.